# Write a program that will search an array to find the first odd number

Tags: java, arrays

I am not able to complete this question.
Write a program that will search an array to find the first odd number. If an odd
number is found, then find the first even number following the odd number. Return the distance between the first odd number and the FIRST even number. Return -1 if no odd numbers are found or there are no even numbers following an odd number.
I tried this questions but i am not able to solve this is my code:

```
public class RayOddtoEven
{
  public static int go(int[] ray)
  {
    int result = 0;
    boolean oddExists = false;
    int oddIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
      if (array[i] % 2 != 0)
      {
        oddExists = true;
        oddIndex = array[i];
        break;
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

Runner for this code

```
class Main 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    RayOddtoEven rt = new RayOddtoEven();

    System.out.println( rt.go( new int[]{7,1,5,3,11,5,6,7,8,9,10,12345,11} ) );
    System.out.println( rt.go( new int[]{11,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,-99,7} ) );
    System.out.println( rt.go( new int[]{10,20,30,40,5,41,31,20,11,7} ) );
    System.out.println( rt.go( new int[]{32767,70,4,5,6,7} ) );
    System.out.println( rt.go( new int[]{2,7,11,21,5,7} ) );
    System.out.println( rt.go( new int[]{7,255,11,255,100,3,2} ) );
    System.out.println( rt.go( new int[]{9,11,11,11,7,1000,3} ) );
    System.out.println( rt.go( new int[]{7,7,7,11,2,7,7,11,11,2} ) );
    System.out.println( rt.go( new int[]{2,4,6,8,8} ) );

  }
}
```

Please help me to complete this code and i give the outputs that this code give with this runner.
I need this answers.
The correct output that i need.

```
6
2
3
1
-1
4
5
4
-1
```

Comment: Your method does not return anything.

Comment: Yeh i know but i do not understand. so that's why i do not return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would nest a loop, first iterate to find the first odd value; then iterate from there forward for an even value. You can terminate the outer loop once you have iterated from the first odd. Something like

```
public static int go(int[] ray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ray.length; i++) {
        if (ray[i] % 2 != 0) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < ray.length; j++) {
                if (ray[j] % 2 == 0) {
                    return j - i;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
6
2
3
1
-1
4
5
4
-1
```